# How do you import artifacts from one Bitbucket pipeline to another?

Tags: continuous-integration, bitbucket-pipelines

We have a complex build system, with a many to many relationship between our libraries and our applications.  We put each library and application in it's own repository, and use the output of the library builds in our application builds.

On our old Jenkins server, we simply set up a custom workspace and checked out the projects into standardized relative paths so they could find each other.  Post build steps assured that only successful builds copied to the central bin folder at the expected relative path.

On our Bamboo server, our repository was fetched to a Checkout Directory at the expected relative path, and we could fetch artifacts from other builds and put them in the central bin folder at the expected relative path.

Now I'm trying to set up some Bitbucket Pipelines builds, and I can't see an obvious way to do a similar thing.  The working folder is set automatically by pipelines, I can't push that repository into a subfolder that is relative to other build outputs.  I can create artifacts, but I can't seem to import them into other pipelines.  I can create caches, but again I can't seem to import them into other pipelines.

Library bitbucket-pipelines.yml

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0

pipelines:
  branches:
     master:
     eCRF2:
        - step:
            name: Build and Test
            caches:
              - dotnetcore
              - platform2
            script:
              - dotnet restore ./NET5/Platform2.sln
              - dotnet build ./NET5/Platform2.sln --no-restore --configuration Release
            artifacts:
              - NET5/Platform2/bin/**
definitions:
    caches:
        platform2: NET5/Platform2/bin
```

App bitbucket-pipelines.yml

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0

pipelines:
  default:
        - step:
            name: Build and Test
            caches:
              - dotnetcore
              - platform2
            script:
              - export PROJECT_NAME=./PlatformDataService.sln
              - dotnet restore ${PROJECT_NAME}
              - dotnet build ${PROJECT_NAME} --no-restore --configuration Release
            artifacts:
              - PlatformDataService/bin/**
```

https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/deploy-build-artifacts-to-bitbucket-downloads/ did get me to upload a file to the Downloads section of the repository, but how do I pull it into the other pipeline?

Is there a way to solve this within bitbucket pipelines itself or do I have to get a nuget server that's available outside my VPN?

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines/integrations?p=atlassian/bitbucket-upload-file did get me to upload a file to the Downloads section of the repository, but how do I pull it into the other pipeline?

Comment: A possibility exists to have a separate repo just for building that has the pipelines file in it, and a bunch of git submodules that import the code in the right relative positions, but that means we rebuild the libraries for every application.

Comment: Nuget didn't like my downloads url as a nuget source.  Maybe could do pre-build step to get the file names available with REST, then download the file, then use a local nuget repository?

Comment: I was about to upvote this question and realized the writing style was awfully familiar...  Tackling the same problem to a different end where nuget is less convenient solution.

Comment: On possible alternative to nuget is git lfs and some other file service.  It still leaves you with the above issues that you have to get the output of one repository into another, but it works for dev environments that don't use nuget.  https://git-lfs.com/

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to solve this within bitbucket pipelines itself or do I have to get a nuget server that's available outside my VPN?

In short, no.  We ended up using an Azure nuget server with our bitbucket pipeline.  As far as I can tell Atlassian doesn't offer a nuget server service, you have to get a third party one.